# Assigning specific colors to bars in Matplotlib radial bar chart (Python3)

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, bar-chart

I am looking to assign specific colors to bars in a bar chart based on numerous nominal and ordinal conditions.

My data looks something like this:

```
Dataset Type        Dataset Count
Image               2
Video               10
Image               12
3D Model            1
Audio               3
```

First, I am looking to assign colors by condition, like the following logic:

```
df['Dataset Type'] == 'Image' then red
df['Dataset Type'] == 'Video' then blue
df['Dataset Type'] == '3D Model' then green
etc.
```

Similarly, I would like to apply logic to numeric values, such as:

```
df['Dataset Count'] <= 5 then hatch (stripe)
df['Dataset Count'] => 6 then hatch (star)
```

I've tried numerous techniques I've found on stackoverflow, but can only get a boolean color option working.

My current code:

```
counts = df['Dataset Count']
labels = df['Dataset'] #the name of the actual datasets I'm examining

iN = len(counts)
arrCnts = np.array(counts)

theta=np.arange(0,2*np.pi,2*np.pi/iN)
width = (2*np.pi)/iN *0.8
bottom = 20

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(30,30))
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.75, 0.75], polar=True)
bars = ax.bar(theta, arrCnts, width=width, bottom=bottom)
plt.axis('off')

rotations = np.rad2deg(theta)
y0,y1 = ax.get_ylim()

for x, bar, rotation, label in zip(theta, bars, rotations, labels):
    offset = (bottom+bar.get_height())/(y1-y0)
    lab = ax.text(0, 0, label, transform=None, 
         ha='center', va='center', size=10)
    renderer = ax.figure.canvas.get_renderer()
    bbox = lab.get_window_extent(renderer=renderer)
    invb = ax.transData.inverted().transform([[0,0],[bbox.width,0] ])
    lab.set_position((x,offset+(invb[1][0]-invb[0][0])/2.*2.7 ) )
    lab.set_transform(ax.get_xaxis_transform())
    lab.set_rotation(rotation)

plt.show()
```

It's current output:

[Radial bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZwux.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Essentially you're asking how to map a column of strings to another column of strings based on a mapping `{"Image" : "red", ....}`. See [pandas.Series.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

Comment: Re: column of strings. This is true for the dataset type, but not the conditional hatching.

Comment: For that you could use [`.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)